# Import decimal coordinates from excel in r

Tags: r, excel, import

I have an excel file with two columns, like this:

```
lon         lat
14,1910200  40,8283663
14,1910947  40,8284298
14,1912717  40,8283315
14,1910512  40,8284435
14,1910553  40,8284285
```

when i try to import it in R with `read.xlsx`, it truncates the last two decimal places.

```
      lon      lat 
1  14.19102 40.82837  
2  14.19109 40.82843  
3  14.19127 40.82833  
4  14.19105 40.82844  
5  14.19106 40.82843
```

if i use `read.xlsx2` it changes lon and lat type to factor and removes decimal zeros.

```
        lon        lat 
1    14.19102 40.8283663  
2  14.1910947 40.8284298  
3  14.1912717 40.8283315  
4  14.1910512 40.8284435  
5  14.1910553 40.8284285
```

There is a function that allows to import all seven decimal digits as numerical type? thanks.

Comment: You are printing with a precision of 5 digits.  It is nothing to do with import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your digits option, and take a look at `?options`:

```
options()$digits
# [1] 7
x <- 1.123456789
x
# [1] 1.123457

options(digits = 10)
x
# [1] 1.123456789
```